# The Management Studio in runtime version of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Does the runtime version of SQL Server have Management Studio?

Comment: Runtime version?!?!?!? What do you mean by that??? SQL Server Management Studio is **an option** when you install SQL Server - the full product. You can install SSMS - or you can leave it out. It's not part of any *runtime* version of SQL Server ....

Answer (score -1):

SQL Server Runtime is an ISV solution.  They sell their product with SQL Server and has limited license rights to use that SQL instance with only their software.  It can't be used or accessed by any other product.  It is a full version of SQL Server and yes you should be able to use Management Studio for that reason.  It is still licensed per device/user or per core.